# App gets rejected by Apple multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I submitted my app multiple times to the App Store and got the same error twice.

> Thank you for your resubmission. We continue to find the following: 2.1 Details During review, your app crashed on an iPad running iOS.

My App is iPhone based so for that I have selected **Target-->General-->Device-->iPhone.**

Also iPhone **Target/Project-->BuildSettings-->TargetIphoneFamily-->1**

So why are they testing my app on iPad since it is configured for iPhone only?

Comment: An iPhone-only app doesn't scale to iPad screens (you get the 1x/2x buttons), but it still has to run on them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually apple provided the guidelines for iphone apps to be approved.

> Section 2.10 says: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without
>   modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution.

check this link

> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Comment: Actually iam using uiimagepickercontroller in my App to open gallery,So for iPhone iam just presenting it to open.So for iPad i need to open gallery using UIPopoverController??.  Iam just thinking this might me the case for the crash in Ipad.?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the application which you develop can be downloaded on iPad from App Store. On iPad it runs with 3.5" device screen size.

So if you have any specific feature like calling then you can display message to user like, `"This device doesn't support this feature"` else the features which are available on iPad should work without any issue.

Comment: Actually iam using uiimagepickercontroller in my App to open gallery,So for iPhone iam just presenting it to open.So for iPad i need to open gallery using UIPopoverController??.  Iam just thinking this might me the case for the crash in Ipad.?